# Stop data duplication in excel VBA code that copies data from one sheet into another

Tags: vba, excel

I've got the following code that takes a record of the busiest hour of each day from sheet and adds it to another.

```
Sub DailySales()
Dim dailySht As Worksheet 'worksheet storing latest          store activity
Dim recordSht As Worksheet 'worksheet to store the   highest period of each day
Dim lColDaily As Integer ' Last column of data in the store activity sheet
Dim lCol As Integer ' Last column of data in the record sheet
Dim maxCustomerRng As Range ' Cell containing the highest number of customers
Dim CheckForDups As Range ' Used to find duplicate dates on the record Sheet
Dim maxCustomerCnt As Long ' value of highest customer count

Set dailySht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Supermarket Data")

Set recordSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Record Data")
With recordSht
    lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
With dailySht
    lColDaily = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    maxCustomerCnt = Application.Max(.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, lColDaily)))
    Set maxCustomerRng = .Range(.Cells(7, 1), .Cells(7, lColDaily)).Find(What:=maxCustomerCnt, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not maxCustomerRng Is Nothing Then
        Set CheckForDups = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(x1ToLeft).Column).Find(What:=maxCustomerRng.Offset(-1, 0).Value, LookIn:x1Values)
        If CheckForDups Is Nothing Then maxCustomerRng.EntireColumn.Copy recordSht.Cells(1, lCol + 1)
    End If
End With

Set maxCustomerRng = Nothing
Set dailySht = Nothing
Set recordSht = Nothing

End Sub
```

I added the following to prevent data duplication  i.e. it should not record more than one data for a single day?

```
 Set CheckForDups = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Find(What:=maxCustomerRng.Offset(-1, 0).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If CheckForDups Is Nothing Then maxCustomerRng.EntireColumn.Copy recordSht.Cells(1, lCol + 1)
```

However I get a "Compile Error: Syntax Error" when I run the code. The following line is highlighted:

```
    Set CheckForDups = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(x1ToLeft).Column).Find(What:=maxCustomerRng.Offset(-1, 0).Value, LookIn:x1Values)
```

This is the table for the first sheet:

```
Customer data   7:00:00 AM  7:30:00 AM  8:00:00 AM  8:30:00 AM  9:00:00 AM  
Number of customers 33         37         110          250        84
Amount spent        65         50          70           85        60
Average time spent  12         10           8           17        10
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have some typos in your code: `x1Left` should be `xlLeft`, `x1Values` should be `xlValues`, and the named parameters should be specified using `:=` instead of `:`.

But the whole statement is not correct, this is the way it should be:

```
Set CheckForDups = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Find(What:=maxCustomerRng.Offset(-1, 0).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

In second `Range` parameter you passed a number of a column, where you intended to pass a cell. So you don't need to get `.Column` property, just the cell itself, which you get by removing `.Column`.

Comment: @YowE3K  - Sorry I only just started to learn this language. I've made the suggested changes and it works but it does not prevent data duplication. Also I'm not sure which Range parameter you're referring to, it does not compile when I remove the .Column

Comment: In the line, that is highlighted.

Comment: It gives me a 'method or data member not found'. This is what I did: Set CheckForDups = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, .Count).End(xlToLeft)).Find(What:=maxCustomerRng.Offset(-1, 0).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)

Comment: Just copy code that I posted, you got it wrong. Please, read carefully answer before asking such questions.

Comment: It compiles and records the data in the second sheet, however it does not prevent data duplication which is what I'm trying to achieve. Can you please take a look at the code and let me know if you see anything else wrong with the it? It does not give me any errors.

Comment: @aab Your check is being done on `dailySht`, but I think you should be doing it on `recordSht`, so try using `Set CheckForDups = recordSht.Range(recordSht.Cells(1, 1), recordSht.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Find(What:=maxCustomerRng.Offset(-1, 0).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)`